# NodeJS | Как человек собирает серверную и клиентскую стороны?

Tags: reactjs, express

Дело в чём: я представил себе, то, что какой-нибудь мой друг программист попросит написать серверную сторону (бек-энд), т.к. он фронт-ендщик. Он написал клиентскую часть приложения с помощью **CRA** (Create React App), а я же написал сервер на **Express** (**JS**). И так вот. Я ему скидываю архив с папкой **server**, он же это скидывает себе на проект. И всё. Так называемое, **MERN** **Stack** приложение завершено. Но у меня вопрос. Как он будет совмещать клиентскую и серверную папки? Как он это будет совмещать, чтобы выкласть на хостинг? Извеняюсь, что возможно, это тупой вопрос, но он немного меня мучает..

Если не понятно представление, [то вот структура:](https://github.com/senthilmca90/mern-crud)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivDjWYcKDZI